# Need to put items from Area to a custom field

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I created a custom field called "Agile Teams" under epic and I need to put all the area items into that "Agile Teams". It need to be auto-populated. Help me in this.

[image]

Comment: You haven't really asked a question... Please refer to [ask] and try to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

In your current situation, we don't have the rules to help you put all the area items into that "Agile Teams". You can try to use the api: [Work Items - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) site, which is our main forum for product suggestions. After suggesting raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team will provide the updates if they view it.